# Apache Airflow - How approach geocoding?

Tags: airflow

Trying to learn Apache Airflow but struggling to understand the best way to approach one particular aspect of my DAG re: geocoding via an external rest API.

Assuming a DAG that:

task 1: Downloads data - stores to CSV.

task 2: Cleans, ETL, etc - writes to database.

Do I then....?

task 3:

- A) Connects to database,
- B) pulls first N records that need geocoded
- C) sends request of first batch to external API and awaits response
- D) writes back to DB.
- E) Rinse and repeat A-D until all records are geocoded
- F) exit task

Is that kind of iterative potentially long running task ok as long as it exits after processing all the records or am I fundamentally misunderstanding / misusing airflow?

Any best practices / examples in public code bases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that approach is fine. You're trying to avoid using XCOM by bundling all of the steps into one operator which I think is a decent idea and a common thing to do.

Something else could do is split the task into some more steps and "rest" the data in between steps, allowing you to have more operators and not use XCOM:

**Operator 1 (Database -> Filesystem)**

- Connect to database
- Run SQL to pull N records from the database
- Write these records to the filesystem as CSV

**Operator 2 (Call API with CSV records)**

- Read records off the filesystem
- Call API with records
- Write new records to the filesystem as CSV

**Operator 3 (Filesystem -> Database)**

- Read records from CSV off the filesystem
- Write records to the database

The advantage of an approach like this is that, say if your API call fails, you don't have to re-run the extraction from the database. You would just restart the API task.

Comment: Really good answer. Thank you SimonD. How would you adopt your pattern above if you had more records to geocode than you could send in one api request, lets say N*10 where N is the amount of records you can send to geocode at one time and N*10 is the amount of records needing geocoding?

Comment: I would make sure that `Operator 2` in my example above had a parameter called `batch_size` or something. The Operator would then only read, send, write `batch_size` number of records until the file is completely read. I'm sure I haven't thought of everything but this just what comes to mind.

Comment: oh ok.. So Operator 2 just iterates until the objective is met and then exits. Makes sense.